# Analyzing large rasters from an image service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, remote-sensing, naip

I'm working with NAIP imagery in ArcGIS 10.4.1 that I'm accessing through the USDA server (https://gis.apfo.usda.gov/arcgis/services).

I want to perform focal statistics on bands 2 and 4 (green and IR), which is easy when the file is hosted locally because I can just double click on the raster and select any of the individual bands.

With this NAIP file however, navigating to the hosted folder in the focal statistics window shows an empty folder. Clipping the NAIP down and saving as a local file is time-consuming and seems to warp the display of the image.

Is it possible to extract bands from non-local rasters?